# how to display image with .tif extension>

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i have a popup page which gets the file path through querystring then displays images,that images are in a folder in my solution.but when i am trying to display a image with .tif extension in same popup page it is not displaying.

Code bihind:

```
       Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim FilePath = Request.QueryString("FilePath")
        Image1.ImageUrl = FilePath
     End Sub
```

design page:

```
 <div>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ControlStyle-Height="800" ControlStyle-Width="800"  />
</div>
```

Comment: Erm, sorry, but I don't understand what the problem is?  As long as the .tif file is referenced correctly (i.e. the file is where it should be, and the link to it is correct) then it should be fine

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501145/displaying-tif-images-in-the-aspimage-control-of-aspnet

Comment: @freefaller-the path is correct and it is inside a folder of my solution.as i am able to show other jpeg files but not .tif files

Comment: As dave is highlighting, make sure IIS has ".tif" listed under the MIME types

Comment: I have tried that also but it did not work

Comment: Sorry, there is simply not enough information provided for anybody to help you (also, make sure that you leave a space after `@user` otherwise the person will not receive a notification of reply)

Comment: @freefaller thanks for the help.But what else should i provide?

Comment: This is such a localised problem, that I'm not sure there is anything you can provide. I would suggest this... check the RENDERED html to make sure that the path to the file is definitely correct, then use your browsers developers tools (F12, I would particularly recommend FireBug for Firefox) to see if it gives any indication of why the .tif is not being loaded/displayed