# Classic ASP: when downloading a tif file, user can't open it

Tags: download, tiff

In my web application (IIS 10), developed in Classic ASP, when I give possibility, for the user, to download a TIF file, it gets the error: "The file is damaged", but the file is actually not really damaged on the file server.

This doesn't happen with PDF in the same folder of the file, they open without problems.

this is the code that i use:

```
Select Case fileType
Case ".pdf"
  'The file, mime and filename can be built-up anyway they don't 
  'have to be hard coded.
  mime = "application/pdf"
  tipoDownload = "inline"

Case ".tif"
  'The file, mime and filename can be built-up anyway they don't 
  'have to be hard coded.
  mime = "image/tiff"
  tipoDownload = "download"

'Case ...
End Select

If Len(file & "") > 0 Then
    
    Set s = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  s.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary 'adTypeBinary = 1 See "Useful Links"
  Call s.Open()
  response.write file
  Call s.LoadFromFile(file)
  bin = s.Read()

  'Clean-up the stream and free memory
  Call s.Close()
  Set s = Nothing

  'Set content type header based on mime variable
  Response.ContentType = mime
  'Control how the content is returned using the 
  'Content-Disposition HTTP Header. Using "attachment" forces the resource
  'to prompt the client to download while "inline" allows the resource to
  'download and display in the client (useful for returning images
  'as the "src" of a <img> tag).
  Call Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "" & tipoDownload & ";filename=" & filename)
  Call Response.BinaryWrite(bin)
Else
  'Return a 404 if there's no file.
  Response.Status = "404 Not Found"
End If
```

Mime Type for .tif is defined (image/tiff).

Can you help me?

thank you very much!
Davide

Comment: What browser is the user using?  Have you tried the other types to see if you get the same results?

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501145/displaying-tif-images-in-the-aspimage-control-of-aspnet

Comment: The user is using Chrome and Firefox, but that problem is not just for one user, it's for everyone. All other types works perfectly, just ".tif" doesn't work. It downloads the file but the user can't open it. (it happens also putting "attachment" in place of "download" )

Comment: I've tried to open the tif file with irfan view, it says that it's impossible to read the file header

Comment: Is it critical it remains in TIFF format?  Because you could just batch convert all the files to PDF or other format and be done with this nightmare, short of the user insiting on creating new tiffs perhaps?